# Is polynomial hull contained in Runge domain?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Suppose $Y$ is a compact set contained in $\Omega$ - a Runge domain, biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$. I would like to prove that polynomial hull of $Y$, $$\bar Y = \{z \in \mathbb{C}^n: |P(z)| \le ||P||_Y, \: \forall P \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C} ^n) \}$$ where $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C} ^n)$ is the space of complex polynomials on $\mathbb{C}^n$, is contained in $\Omega$. Unfortunately I am not able to do that but at the same time I feel that assumption on being biholomorphic with $\mathbb{C}^n$ may be artificial.

Comment: I think the assumption of biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$ is also artificial, biholomorphic mappings preserve holomorphically convex hulls, that is all I am aware of.

Comment: What is your definition of a Runge domain? [EOM](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Runge_domain) has two kinds of Runge domains. The more common terminology is, I think, that Runge domains are what EOM calls Runge domains of the first kind, i.e. every holomorphic function on $\Omega$ can be approximated, uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$, by entire functions [equivalently, by polynomials]. Is that your definition, or is it the second kind?

Comment: @DanielFischer Approximation on compacts of $\Omega$ of holomorphic functions on $\Omega$ by polynomials, i.e. the first kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption that $\Omega$ is biholomorphically equivalent to $\mathbb{C}^n$ is not superfluous. By Hartogs' Kugelsatz, every holomorphic function on a spherical shell $U = \{z \in \mathbb{C}^n : 1 < \lVert z\rVert < 2\}$ has a holomorphic extension to the ball $B = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}^n : \lVert z\rVert < 2\}$ when $n \geqslant 2$. So the restriction $\rho_U \colon \mathscr{O}(B) \to \mathscr{O}(U)$ is a bijection. Since $B$ is a Runge domain and "$\mathscr{O}(U) =  \mathscr{O}(B)$", so is $U$, but the polynomial hull of $Y = \{ z \in U : \lVert z\rVert = 3/2\}$ is the ball $\{ z : \lVert z\rVert \leqslant 3/2\}$ is not contained in $U$.

The short form of the argument is:

1. Since $\Omega$ is a Runge domain, we have $\overline{Y} \cap \Omega = \hat{Y}$, where $\hat{Y}$ is the holomorph-convex hull of $Y$, $$\hat{Y} = \{z \in \Omega : f\in \mathscr{O}(\Omega) \implies \lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_Y\}.$$
2. Since $\Omega$ is biholomorphically equivalent to $\mathbb{C}^n$, it is a domain of holomorphy, hence $\Omega$ is holomorphically convex, therefore $\hat{Y}$ is a compact subset of $\Omega$.
3. The polynomial hull $\overline{Y}$ cannot have components contained in $\mathbb{C}^n\setminus \Omega$.

Part 1 is straightforward. Since [the restriction of] every polynomial $P$ belongs to $\mathscr{O}(\Omega)$ we have $\hat{Y} \subset \overline{Y}\cap \Omega$. And if $z_0 \in \Omega \setminus \hat{Y}$, there is an $f\in \mathscr{O}(\Omega)$ with $\lvert f(z_0)\rvert > \lVert f\rVert_Y$. Let

$$\varepsilon = \frac{\lvert f(z_0)\rvert - \lVert f\rVert_Y}{2},$$

and $P$ a polynomial with $\lVert f - P\rVert_{Y \cup \{z_0\}} < \varepsilon$. Such a polynomial exists since $\Omega$ is a Runge domain. Then $\lvert P(z_0)\rvert - \lVert P\rVert_Y > 0$, i.e. $z_0 \notin \overline{Y}$. Thus $\Omega\setminus \hat{Y} \subset \Omega \setminus \overline{Y}$ and the proof of 1 is complete.

Part 2 is not trivial, but a well-known fact about domains of holomorphy, the Cartan-Thullen theorem.

Part 3 isn't trivial either. It's an easy consequence of the Oka-Weil theorem - if $K \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is compact and polynomially convex, then every holomorphic function on [a neighbourhood of] $K$ can be uniformly approximated [on $K$] by polynomials.

In our situation, $K = \overline{Y}$ is a compact polynomially convex set, and $K = \hat{Y} \cup (\overline{Y}\setminus \Omega)$ is a decomposition into two disjoint compact sets. A polynomial approximation of

$$f(z) = \begin{cases} 0 &, z \in \hat{Y} \\ 1 &, z \in \overline{Y}\setminus \Omega \end{cases}$$

with an error less than $\frac{1}{2}$ shows $\overline{Y}\setminus \Omega = \varnothing$.

The Oka-Weil theorem is not trivial, however. (It's theorem 1.5 in chapter VI of R. M. Range's *Holomorphic Functions and Integral Representaions in Several Complex Variables* for example, where you can find a proof.)

Comment: May I ask how you think of a polynomially convex hull compared to a holomorphically convex hull intuitively?

Comment: I don't think intuitively. For $n = 1$, we have the informal description that the polynomially convex hull adjoins all bounded components of the complement of $K$, and the holomorphically convex hull only those that are contained in the domain. For $n > 1$ it's "similar but way more complicated", mostly because not every domain is a domain of holomorphy in higher dimensions.